# NSTreeController addChild: does not call newObject but add: does (Class/Object mode)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstreecontroller

I noticed that my subclass os NSTreeController runs `newObject` only when the `add:` method is called but never for `addChild:`

I found [this thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/139753-problem-overriding-newobject-in-nstreecontroller.html) discussing the very same issue. Though in this case the user is using the tree controller in Core Data mode, however I have mine set to use a specific Class (object mode).

**What reason could there be for `addChild:` not using the `newObject` method?**

If `newObject` gets called for `add:` I see no reason why it shouldn't work for `addChild:`. I confirmed this behavior in Apple's SourceView demo app by replacing OutlineController with a subclass, and connecting buttons to `add:` and `addChild:` - again only `add:` calls `newObject`. I find this really really really weird behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Found the [answer in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/CntrlContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002147-183473):

> The add: and insert: actions use the newObject method to create the
>   object that is added to the collection. In object mode the addChild:,
>   and insertChild: create objects of the class specified by objectClass,
>   but do not use the newObject method to do so.

At least it says that's the way it is. Though it contradicts the Class Reference. And they neglected to explain why it is the way it is.

Comment: I speculate that it has something to do with avoiding initWithEntity when the children inserted can be of several subclasses, but I struggle to reconcile that speculation with the terrible documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> What reason could there be for addChild: not using the newObject method?

It depends on context.  If the `NSTreeController` is talking to Plain Old Objects, it *will* run `-newObject` in the context of `-addChild`, because given the known `-objectClass`, the tree controller has all the information it needs in order to put everything in the right place.

If `NSTreeController` is talking to an `NSManagedObjectContext,` it *will not* run `-newObject`, because the `-newObject` implementation won't have enough context to establish the relationship with the selection, and the relationship must be in place once `-addChild:` is finished.

Comment: no matter which context (coredata/managed or objectClass) addChild: never sends the newObject message (see my answer, the programming guide says addChild: will not issue newObject while the class reference states the opposite)